# Using ng-repeat and $index how to set default selected in select

Tags: angularjs, select

Using ng-repeat and $index how to show default selected value using angularjs

my code :
I have SelectValues :

```
"Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type": [
{
  "id": 33, 
  "value": "Earrings"
}, 
{
  "id": 35, 
  "value": "Gemstones"
}, 
{
  "id": 34, 
  "value": "Loose Diamonds"
}, 
{
  "id": 32, 
  "value": "Necklaces"
}, 
{
  "id": 31, 
  "value": "Pendants"
}, 
{
  "id": 30, 
  "value": "Rings"
} ]

selected Value is "Earings"
```

In my HTML

```
 <select ng-model="categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[$index]" ng-init="categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[$index] = SelectValues.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type.indexOf(0)" ng-options="option.value for option in SelectValues.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type track by option.id">
```

If I wrote like this means no value as selected by default. I need exact selected Values based on the $index.

Comment: ng-model="categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[$index].value . Try this

Comment: @RaviTeja Not Working

Comment: Try like this, am not sure whether it will work or not ng-init="categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[$index] = SelectValues.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type.indexOf(0).value"

Comment: Set a variable on scope and assign it to one of objects value like $scope.selectedType = $scope.categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[0].valu‌​e . Then ng-model = "selectedType"

Comment: Where is the $index coming from ? is this dropdown in an ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-options

```
 <select ng-model="value" ng-init="value='Earrings'"   ng-options="mode.value as mode.value for mode in storageResult.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type">
  </select>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrDDsXJ01jH3FxlGoKF2?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

In a select, ng-model will determine which option is selected.

So if you strictly want to select an item by its index in the array you need to create the object model like so:

```
$scope.selected = $scope.values[0];
```

values being your json array.

The select will then look like:

```
    <select
      ng-model="selected"
      ng-options="option.value for option in values track by option.id">
   </select>
```

Don't use ng-init in the html, it's bad practice.

```js
function MyController() {
    this.values =  [
    {
      "id": 33, 
      "value": "Earrings"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 35, 
      "value": "Gemstones"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 34, 
      "value": "Loose Diamonds"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 32, 
      "value": "Necklaces"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 31, 
      "value": "Pendants"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 30, 
      "value": "Rings"
    } ];
    this.selected = this.values[0];
  };

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <select
        ng-model="ctrl.selected"
        ng-options="option.value for option in ctrl.values track by option.id">
    </select>
    <br>
    {{ctrl.selected | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/hn3taeeo/26/). "School 1" and "Campus 1" shall be selected by default

Comment: @Ben10 this is completely different from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id where default selected value is available you can include it in a scope variable and inject the variable in

```
<option value="">{{selectedType}}</option>

$scope.selectedType= categoryval.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[defaultIndex].valu‌​e
```

value ="" helps you to fill the empty first option

Comment: how will do that for this scenario jsfiddle.net/hn3taeeo/24

Answer (score 0):

Remove ng-init and set default value in controller so that you can unit test whether default option is always what you want it to be.

In controller:

```
$scope.defaultValue =  $scope.SelectValues.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type[0];
```

then change HTML

```
<select ng-model="defaultValue"  ng-options="option.value for option in SelectValues.Jewelery_And_Diamond_Type track by option.id">
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TRzeFTwtAOEVDNzz2BiT?p=preview)

Comment: how will do that for this scenario jsfiddle.net/hn3taeeo/24